# CMD Powercfg command fails when launched from HTA VBScript

Tags: cmd, vbscript, hta, powercfg

I have the following HTA file:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>test</title>
<SCRIPT Language="VBScript"> 
createobject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe", "/k powercfg /batteryreport", "", "runas", 1
</SCRIPT>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

When I run it, it shows a UAC prompt with "yes"/"no" buttons from "Windows Command Processor." After "yes" is clicked, it opens a command prompt window with the title "Administrator: C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cmd.exe". **However the command fails, stating that "The Power Efficiency Diagnostic library (energy.dll) could not be loaded."**

**I am pretty sure the command window that opens has admin permissions** because of the following reasons:

1. It shows a UAC box to open the CMD window
2. The VBScript command was supposed to run the external command with elevated permissions
3. When I run the following command in that same command window, it says "Success": `net session >nul 2>&1 && echo Success || echo Failure`. (This command checks for admin permissions; I found in a comment on this post: https://superuser.com/a/667745
4. The title says "Administrator:" in it.

So, **I am wondering why this command doesn't work and how I can get it to work, if possible.**

Another interesting thing I noticed was that taking line 5 (`createobject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe", "/k powercfg /batteryreport", "", "runas", 1`) from that HTA file and putting it in a blank .VBS file actually leads to a different result. The title of the resulting Command Window with this method is different ("Administrator: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"), and the resulting error is different, too. It says:

> Enabling tracing for 60 seconds...
> Observing system behavior...
> Could not open the Power Efficiency Diagnostic ETW session.  The ETW session is already in use.  Ensure that no other instances of PowerCfg are currently running.

Does anyone have a potential explanation or solution to this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the problem. The question https://stackoverflow.com/a/10989048/18020746 led me in the right direction.

Like the above linked answer states, 64-bit MSHTA cannot run 32-bit files like `powercfg.exe`. But when running the HTA file through the 32-bit version of MSHTA by typing `START C:\Windows\System32\mshta.exe [path to the HTA file]` into the command prompt, the powercfg command works.